# Facebook Login Not Working Due to HTTPS issue MERN

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement facebook login on my React App using `react-google-login`.

```
import React from 'react';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

function OAuthButton() {
    const onResponseFacebook = (res: any) => {
        console.log('Login response:', res);
    };

    return (
        <div>

            <FacebookLogin appId={process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_ID} callback={onResponseFacebook} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default OAuthButton;
```

The button is displayed correctly but then[image]

I'm just developing the app on CRA dev server(localhost:3000). I tried to go to the settings in facebook developers but it does not allow to disable "enforce HTTPS"

[image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `HTTPS = true` in your `.env` file

Comment: Sorry mate! No difference at all. Thanks for the attempt though!